# Zend url()...what is it actually doing?

Tags: zend-framework

What does:

```
$this->url(array(), 'home');
```

and

```
$this->url(array('page' => 'services'), 'static-content');
```

actually do when using the zend framework?

Comment: Take a look at the docs:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html

Answer (score 0):

That will build a `url` for eg:

```
echo $this->url(
    array('controller' => 'foo', 'action' => 'bar', 'param1' => '1')
);
```

will get you

```
/foo/bar/param1/1
```

Answer (score 0):

A little context, **url** is a Zend framework view helper that allows you to build full URLs based on a set parameters. From the official documentation regarding <kbd>[View Helpers - Initial Helpers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html)</kbd>:

> url($urlOptions, $name, $reset, $encode): Creates a URL string based on a named route. $urlOptions should be an associative array of key/value pairs used by the particular route.

On the 1st parameter `$urlOptions` you can provide a variety of data like:

- controller;
- action;
- named parameters for the controller/action you want.

The 2nd parameter `$name` relates to a given route.

Answering your question, the 1st example, `$this->url(array(), 'home');` would generate the URL for you currently loaded controller/action using the `home` route.

The 2nd usage, `$this->url(array('page' => 'services'), 'static-content');`, would generate an URL for your currently load controller/action using the `static-content` route and passing a `page` argument with `services` as its value.

You can read all you need to know in the <kbd>[Zend_Controller_Router](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html)</kbd> documentation.